# Class does not exist laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

```
namespace MyApp\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class CreateAdminGroup extends FormRequest
{
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

My Controller:

```
 namespace MyApp\Http\Controllers\Administration\Resource;

 use MyApp\Http\Requests\Admin\Admin\CreateAdminGroup;
```

But i get an error that Class SwapSome\Http\Requests\Admin\Admin\CreateAdminGroup does not exist

Why do I get this error, the request is there, everything shuold be good.
My request in the App\Http\Requests\Admin\Admin\ folder

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Change request's namespace to:
`namespace MyApp\Http\Requests\Admin\Admin;`

Comment: Thanks, now i get a forbidden error message, but i think that means that this error is gone! Thank you! :)

Comment: @user3844579 Forbidden error is because of `authorize` method which returns false. Just change it to `return true` and it will work just fine :)